# xcode sprite game error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCKION(code=EXC_1386, subcode=0x0),after launching simulator

Tags: xcode

Hi I am following my Xcode game tutorials. when I run the simulator it successfully launches but it crashes as soon as I click to see next page. and then error pops up on 
GameScene.swift

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
         cannon = self.childNodeWithName("cannon") as! SKSpriteNode
```

Right above is the part I have a error. from

```
cannon = self.childNodeWithName("cannon") as! SKSpriteNode
```

and the error shows like this

```
thread1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCKION(code=EXC_1386, subcode=0x0)
```

this is my code

import SpriteKit

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var cannon: SKSpriteNode!
    var touchLocation:CGPoint = CGPointZero


    **override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
         cannon = self.childNodeWithName("cannon") as! SKSpriteNode**

    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */
        touchLocation = touches.first!.locationInNode(self)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        touchLocation = touches.first!.locationInNode(self)

    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
         let percent = touchLocation.x / size.width
         let newAngle = percent * 180 - 180
         cannon.zRotation = CGFloat(newAngle) * CGFloat(M_PI); 180.0
```

Please let me know what is wrong here. very frustrating. thanks

Comment: did you try to comment out  cannon = self.childNodeWithName("cannon") as! SKSpriteNode**

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code in a new project and it works if the childNodeWithName is correct. I presume you have created the cannon in GameScene.sks and are now trying to reference it in code.

If the sprite in the .sks file is called "cannon" it works fine, however if I change it to something else I also get a crash.

In short your cannon sprite name is not "cannon" so there must be a spelling error somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you solved it already, but I was watching the same tutorial and found the same issue.

The problem is with how the `cannon` node is parented to the `cannon_full` node. The `self.childNodeWithName("cannon")` doesn't look through nested object.

To fix the problem, parent the `cannon` sprite node to the SKScene instead or find it with `self.childNodeWithName("cannon_full")?.self.childNodeWithName("cannon")`  where `cannon_full` is the parent name. Both are valid approaches, although the second one will cause positioning issues in this specific case.